# How to display scrollbar in list after certain dimension?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this list:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
 <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-pills-primary nav-pills-icons flex-column">
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#link10">
      <i class="tim-icons icon-istanbul"></i> Home
      </a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#link11">
      <i class="tim-icons icon-settings"></i> Settings
      </a>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to show a scrollbar when the list reach a specific number of items eg: 3, how can I do this?

You can check the list above working in `Vertical Tabs With Icons` example [here](https://demos.creative-tim.com/marketplace/black-dashboard-pro/examples/components/panels.html).

Comment: Cant you use overflow-y: auto;height:90px; on the UL element? and set fixed heights on the li's to 30px?

Comment: @Chris I implemented your solution but the element of the list goes in horizontal, but I need to keep that in vertical

Comment: I changed the display type of the UL from flex to block, and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
.nav {
    display: block;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
    height: 360px;
    width: 150px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
ol li, ul li {
    color: #fff;
    height: 118px;
}
```